# yii2 using HTML::checkboxlist get checked value in index.php

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a list of data that I want to put in a `checkboxList`.

```
$data = [
    ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'emel'],
    ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'makluman'],
    ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'memo'],
];

$list = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name');

return Html::checkboxList(
    'roles',
    [],
    $list,
    [
        'itemOptions' => [
            'onclick' => 'myFunction()',
            'id' => 'check',
        ],
    ]
);
```

I can return the result, the problem is I can't get the data that I checked.

Below is my script code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').val();
    console.log(result);
}
</script>
```

When I check the first box it will get the value 1, but when I check the second box it will return 1 when it's supposed to return the value 2. When I uncheck the first box then it returns 2.

I want it to save in one var. For example:

I check first box,

```
a = ["1"]
```

then I check the second box

```
a = ["1","2"]
```

and so on.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things you should look at

1. There are more than 1 elements being selected when you check the second checkbox, you need to iterate all the checked boxes and push into an array by using jquery's `$.each()` otherwise it will just return the first element value.
2. You should use event delegation for binding click see [Why](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/).
3. You are providing an `id` via `itemOptions` to the `checkboxList()` which is technically wrong as it would assign that same `id` to all the checkboxes and you will be experiencing strange behaviors working with them in `javascript` or `html`, you should use the [`item`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#activeCheckboxList()-detail) option which takes a callback `function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value)` and provide unique ids to every input.

See the below code how to use all of the above

- On top of your view add the following

  ```
  $js = <<<JS
      function myFunction() {
          var result=[];

          $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index,checkbox){
              result.push($(checkbox).val());
          });

          console.log(result);
      }

      $(document).on("click",'input[type="checkbox"]',myFunction);

  JS;
  $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
  ```
- Then update the code for your checkbox to below

  ```
  $data = [
      ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'emel'],
      ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'makluman'],
      ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'memo'],
  ];

  $list = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'name');

  echo Html::checkboxList('roles', [], $list, [
      'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
          $return = '<label>';
          $return .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" ' . $checked . ' id="check-' . $index . '" />';
          $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
          $return .= '</label>';
          return $return;
      },
  ]);
  ```